# Chosen Select jquery Not Working in Plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

For some reason js and css files are not loading in my plugin. Here's what I have: (ostensibly unrelated code replaced with '...')

```
class Location_Specific_Menu_Items {
    private static $instance = null;
    public static function get_instance() {
        return null == self::$instance ? self::$instance = new self : self::$instance;
    }

function __construct() {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        ...
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'xsmi_load_admin_script' ) );
    } else {
        ...
}

function xsmi_load_admin_script() {
    wp_enqueue_style('chosen.min', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css');       
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('chosen.jquery.min', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
} // I tried locally hosted files as well.
...
function option( $fields, $item_id ) {
    ob_start(); ?>
        <p class="field-visibility description description-wide">
            <label for="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
            <?php echo 'LSMI Visibility Control' ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
                $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            });
            </script>
            <br/><br/>
            <select name="chzn-select" class="chzn-select" multiple="true" width="200px">
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
...
```

Yet it just looks like this:
[image]

If I comment out

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    });
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ok, css and js are now loading from the CDN. However, the width of the field is still 0px!

Comment: Does your console prints out any errors?

Comment: @denis.stoyanov Could you elaborate? This is my first attempt to build a plugin so I'm still learning some of the basics as I go along.

Comment: Ah-ha. `[Mon Feb 15 17:56:48.254480 2016] [core:error] [pid 4404:tid 1348] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 127.0.0.1:60342] AH00127: Cannot map GET /wpC:Amppswwwwpwp-contentpluginslocation-specific-menu-items/assets/chosen.jquery.min.js?ver=4.4.2 HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://127.0.0.1/wp/wp-admin/nav-menus.php` But no errors after I switched to externally hosted files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it...

```
function xsmi_load_admin_script() {
    wp_register_style( 'chosencss', plugins_url( 'assets/chosen.css', __FILE__ ), true, '', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'chosenjs', plugins_url( 'assets/chosen.jquery.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chosencss' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chosenjs' );
```

}